# How to get the git SHA1 value in the Implementation-Version field in the manifest for a Maven project?

Tags: java, git, maven, logback, mavanagaiata

We use git and maven and logback.

This mean that the stack traces in the log show the Implementation-Version of the jar containing each line in the stack trace (see http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html#packagingData for an example).

So if we can package the SHA1 of the current build into that field in the manifest of the artifact being built, it is very easy to locate the exact source from git that generated the artifact containing that individual line in the source.

According to http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestEntries.html the way to do this is to have a `<key>value</key>` line in the maven-jar-plugin part of the pom.  This would in my case mean

```
<Implementation-Version>FooBar</Implementation-Version>
```

which results in

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3:jar (default-jar) on project axsFTP: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3:ja
r for parameter manifest: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.archiver.ManifestConfiguration for 'implementationVersion' -> [Help 1]
```

Given that I can get the SHA1 from https://github.com/koraktor/mavanagaiata how do I get this correctly set in the MANIFEST.MF file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check that the `<Implementation-Version>` is inside a `<manifestEntries>` element, and not a `<manifest>` element.

Example:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.koraktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>mavanagaiata</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>git-commit</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>commit</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Implementation-Version>${mvngit.commit.id}</Implementation-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Ok, this works.  Thought I'd tested those too, oh well.  Thanks.

Comment: Die Versiosnummer von mavanagaiata ist mittlerweile 0.7.2. Dies hat einige kleinere Probleme bei mir beseitigt (git-Archiv finden etc.)

Comment: As of 2018 I have used pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin in another project with good results.  Both setting properties and writing a property file.